# iPhone - tracking back button

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, nsfilemanager

I have a tableView which lists the contents of my document directory. I have some zip files in that. If I touch a file in the tableView, the corresponding zip file is unzipped and extracted in a temporary directory(`newFilePath` in my case). The contents unzipped is listed in the next tableView. When I touch the back button, the contents in the directory is listed again.

For example, consider that I have four zip files in my document directory.

songs.zip, videos.zip, files.zip, calculation.zip

When I run the application, all the four files are listed in the tableView. When I touch songs.zip, this file is extracted in the `newFilePath` and its contents are pushed to the next tableView. When I touch back, the previous tableView, i.e, the four files in the document directory are listed again. Everything works perfect.

The problem is, the extracted files in the `newFilePath` remains there itself. They occupy the memory unnecessarily. I want them to be removed from that path when I touch the back button, i.e, I want to make `newFilePath` empty when the back button is touched.

I tried for it. But, no use. I tried `removeItemAtPath:` method in `viewWillAppear:` and also in `viewWillDisappear:`. But it didnt work in both the cases.

Is there any other method to track the action of the back button? I want an event to take place when the back button is touched. So please help me by sharing your ideas. Here is my code for your verification.

This is my `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`

```
    NSString *filePath = //filePath
    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        NSLog(@"File exists at path: %@", filePath);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"File does not exists at path: %@", filePath);
    }       
    ZipArchive *zip = [[ZipArchive alloc] init];
    NSString *newFilePath = //newFilePath
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:newFilePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:nil];
    BOOL result = NO;

    if([zip UnzipOpenFile:filePath]) {

        //zip file is there

        if ([zip UnzipFileTo:newFilePath overWrite:YES]) {

            //unzipped successfully

            NSLog(@"Archive unzip Success");

            result= YES;

        } else {

            NSLog(@"Failure To Extract Archive, maybe password?");

        }

    } else  {

        NSLog(@"Failure To Open Archive");

    }

    iDataTravellerAppDelegate *AppDelegate = (iDataTravellerAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    //Prepare to tableview.
    MyFilesList *myFilesList = [[MyFilesList alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyFilesList" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

    //Increment the Current View
    myFilesList.CurrentLevel += 1;

    viewPushed = YES;
    //Push the new table view on the stack
    myFilesList.directoryContent = [AppDelegate getTemporaryDirectoryItemList:newFilePath];
    [myFilesList setTitle:detailedViewController.strName];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:myFilesList animated:YES];
    [myFilesList release];
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Did `removeItemAtPath:` fail, or was `viewWillDisappear:` not called?

Comment: Actually I am using the above code in MyFilesList.m only. So, if I use removeItemAtPath: in viewWillDisappear: it clears the newFilePath as soon as the file is extracted. Its calling removeItemAtPath: and its not working because I am calling the function MyFilesList in MyFilesList.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh ya, thats quite simple:

in LoadView,

```
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                            initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                   target:self 
                                                   action:@selector(backButtonHit)];

-(void)backButtonHit
{
// removeItemAtPath: newFilepath stuff here
  [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. Where should I place this?         self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                            initWithTitle:@"Back" 
                                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain 
                                                   target:self 
                                                   action:@selector(backButtonHit)];

Comment: you can put in ViewDidLoad also.

Comment: oh yaa, I never use the InterfaceBuilder, so its loadview for me and viewDidLoad for all you folks. can you place a breakpoint and check if backButtonHit method is being called. if it is, and if it navigates back, then the removeItemAtPath logic is wrong...